# Drush make command error when unzipping superfish module / library

Tags: drush, navigation

I am moving a website from my local machine to the prod server. I intend to do this with drush sync, looks like the most straightforward way. So, I've created a makefile on my local website, when i issue drush make myfile.make, I get this error :

```
superfish-7.x-1.9 downloaded.                                                               [ok]
Found makefile: superfish.make                                                              [ok]
superfish downloaded from https://github.com/mehrpadin/Superfish-for-Drupal/zipball master. [ok]
Unable to unzip /tmp/make_tmp_1386076010_529dd76a9b232/master.                              [error]
```

Then in tried another download link, fail with same message.

```
superfish downloaded from https://github.com/mehrpadin/Superfish-for-Drupal/archive/1.x.zip. [ok]
Unable to unzip /tmp/make_tmp_1386076010_529dd76a9b232/1.x.zip.                              [error]
```

I guess all zip files are not corrupt, something must be wrong, may be on my local install, but the error message isn't very helpful so I am stuck.

so what to do then ? anyway to fix this ? I guess the superfish module will not be installed if I move my website with drush sync ? can I reinstall superfish  with admin GUI then ?

Answer (score 4):

Unzipping files needs, simply, the unzip program. Check that you have `unzip`-package installed on your server.